# Apex Deprecated Notice

Tags: apex, deprecated, annotations

Is there a good way to announce that the method of the apex class has been deprecated?

`@deprecated` is only available in managed packages, which allow other developers to see the cancellation line when calling method.

I hope that other developers will be able to recognize that the existing method has been deprecated when providing improved methods.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - deprecate annotation is only available for managed package.  Is your need to do the similar thing in an unmanaged package or simply in your org code?

If yes, that is where the naming / coding convention come into picture.   You may create your own standards, which you can propagate to your developers to follow a pattern/(custom) standard (including, completely dummy-out the method or rename it or whatever standard that suits you).